# How to pass Named Parameter in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

Below is the shell script using getopts

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "USER:PWD:JOBID:PROJECTID:" flag
do
         case "${flag}" in
                USER) TEST_USER=${OPTARG};;
                PWD) TEST_PWD=${OPTARG};;
                JOBID) TEST_JOBID=${OPTARG};;
                PROJECTID) TEST_PROJECTID=${OPTARG};;
         esac
       
done
echo "USER: $TEST_USER";
echo "PWD: $TEST_PWD";
echo "JOBID: $TEST_JOBID";                  
echo "PROJECTID: $TEST_PROJECTID"; 

Continue of script i have not put here and if above commands work fine then my issue solve
```

And Here what im running output in terminal, Which one is a correct way to get output command

```
./getopts.sh -USER=devops@gmail.com -PWD=xxxxxx -JOBID=8a809e2496 -PROJECTID=80e2ea54b231f
OR
./getopts.sh USER=devops@gmail.com PWD=xxxxxx JOBID=8a809e2496 PROJECTID=80e2ea54b231f
```

After running above command im getting empty response or string
USER:
PWD:
JOBID:
PROJECTID:

Comment: As an aside, [you want to avoid upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read the getopts manual page

```
    while getopts "U:P:J:I:" flag
    do
             case "${flag}" in
                    U) TEST_USER=${OPTARG};;
                    P) TEST_PWD=${OPTARG};;
                    J) TEST_JOBID=${OPTARG};;
                    I) TEST_PROJECTID=${OPTARG};;
             esac
    done
    echo "USER: $TEST_USER";
    echo "PWD: $TEST_PWD";
    echo "JOBID: $TEST_JOBID";
    echo "PROJECTID: $TEST_PROJECTID";
```

```
./getopts.sh -U devops@gmail.com -P xxxxxx -J 8a809e2496 -I 80e2ea54b231f
```

```
USER: devops@gmail.com
PWD: xxxxxx
JOBID: 8a809e2496
PROJECTID: 80e2ea54b231f
```

With getopt, it's more complicated, but it allows long options and "=".

```
    #!/bin/bash
    TEMP=$(getopt -n "$0" -a -l "user:,password:,jobid:,projectid:" -- -- "$@")

    [ $? -eq 0 ] || exit

    eval set --  "$TEMP"

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
             case "$1" in
                    --user) TEST_USER="$2"; shift;;
                    --password) TEST_PWD="$2"; shift;;
                    --jobid) TEST_JOBID="$2"; shift;;
                    --projectid) TEST_PROJECTID="$2"; shift;;
                    --) shift;;
             esac
             shift;
    done
    echo "USER: $TEST_USER";
    echo "PWD: $TEST_PWD";
    echo "JOBID: $TEST_JOBID";
    echo "PROJECTID: $TEST_PROJECTID";
```

Some tests:

```
$ ./test.sh -user=jules -password=kabas -jobid 5555 -projectid 999 -c
./test.sh: unrecognized option '-c'

$ ./test.sh -user=jules -password=kabas -jobid 5555 -projectid 999   
USER: jules
PWD: kabas
JOBID: 5555
PROJECTID: 999
```

Comment: i tried with this command its not working ./getopts.sh -U=devops@gmail.com -P=xxxxxx -J=8a809e2496 -I=80e2ea54b231f

Comment: I've never seen the "=" being used on unix/linux commandline parameters.

Comment: my client want to have like this it is possible 
while getopts "user:password:jobId:projectId:" flag
    do
             case "${flag}" in
                    user) TEST_USER=${OPTARG};;
                    password) TEST_PWD=${OPTARG};;
                    jobId) TEST_JOBID=${OPTARG};;
                    projectId) TEST_PROJECTID=${OPTARG};;

./getopts.sh -user devops@gmail.com -password xxxxxx -jobId 8a809e2496 -projectId 80e2ea54b231f

when i try im not getting any response or empty strings return please do let me know can i do it

Comment: There's little that's impossible in IT.  All depends on how much one wants to invest in the solution.  See my edit.

Comment: [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: They pick nits, don't they?

Comment: Thanks it solve my issue but i need script explanation why we are using TEMP=$(getopt -n "$0" -a -l -- -- "$@") [ $? -eq 0 ] || exit eval set -- "$TEMP" while [ $# -gt 0 ]  case "$1" in esac shift;    ...........any links to read

Comment: I first read "man getopt" and that pointed me to /usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.*.  Then some trial and error led me to the above script.

Comment: wow thanks @GerardH.Pille your are great i would like to connect with u to learn more about script or any other technologies which u have more experience in it

Comment: That may be so, but I'm not a good teacher - much too impatient.  But any time you have a problem, post it here and give me a heads up.